# How to execute Query Select that WHERE clause using ARRAY Variable in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, arrays, select

i have a code input array like this the variable name is **"output"**
Assume that variable "output" is a list of a Column_Name in Array. the real output i want to get is the list of Table_name and Column_Name that i will show in the Jtable that i have set. the main of things to do is how to execute those Query using all of the "output" values so i can get every Table_Name of its

```
String[] output= example.split(",");
```

after i got an Array list i want to execute one by one of the Array value to a SQL statement and the processing code is like this

```
for (String outputInsert : output) {
    try {
        rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='"+sqldb+ "' AND COLUMN_NAME = '"+outputInsert+"';");           
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Retrieve.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
} result rs2;
```

but i didn't get the result that i want that show all the value of every executed SQL statement

Comment: Can you be more specific on what output you do get and what does your logger show? Also it would be nice if for that case show the input too, I suspect the problem is in typos/quotemarks.

Comment: what does result rs2; and the end ?!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there is a list of value for a given column value , instead of hitting data base for every value,please try with IN clause in  sql query.
NOTE: There is a limitation maximum value can pass in IN clause.

Comment: that does not address the question - its not about efficiency, and I doubt it would improve in this case critically

Comment: I thought how to pass array value to a select query if that is not the case ,then can you please clarify

Comment: read the question itself, not the title. She doesn't get valid rs2 all the time.

Comment: may be it's not answering how to execute the Array list but it give me a new perspective for Using IN for my Query. thankyou so much i will try this

Answer (score 0):

You need to use addBatch and executeBatch commands instead of executeQuery. Please refer to this post [Execute multiple SQL statements in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157194/execute-multiple-sql-statements-in-java).

```
stmt.addBatch(query1);
stmt.addBatch(query2);

stmt.executeBatch();
```